# Как записать дату в .xlsx через PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

День добрый. Разбираюсь в PHPExcel. Код:

```
$my_date = date('d.m.y', time()+60*20);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D2')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('DD.MM.YYYY');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D1', $my_date);
```

В документе ячейка принимает нужный формат (DD.MM.YYYY), но записывается дата с апострофом в начале ('), т.е. в итоге вместо 27.02.2016 в ячейке '27.02.2016

Использую open office, сохраняю в xlsx.
Что еще добавить, чтобы записана была дата без апострофа?

Полный код:

```
include('xlsx/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
include('xlsx/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php');
include('xlsx/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php');
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$start = 3;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('DD.MM.YYYY');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', date('d.m.Y', time()+60*($start + 3)));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('DD.MM.YYYY');
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('text.xls');
```

Answer (score 1):

Решения:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', '=NOW()+0.00001*60*'.$start);
```

и

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1',
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(time()+60*($start + 3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

сделал php файл, который генерирует excel, вставил туда ваши строчки с кодом, у меня апострофа нет. Киньте весь код, видимо где то в др месте ошибка.

Comment: Да весь код - это подлючение класса, создание экземпляра, эти строки, а после - метод класса для сохранения.
Вы создавал excel без дополнительных библиотек?

Comment: вставил ваш полный код, апострофа не появилось, ерунда какая то))

Comment: мне бы так =) но я решил способами ниже